A question about the definition of the normal variation of a tensor field
My question comes from the proof of Prop. 7.32 in Dan Lee's book Geometric relativity.
The setting is we have a hypersurface $\Sigma$ with unit normal $\nu$ in an initial data set $(M, g, k)$. We now want to calculate the normal variation of $k(\nu,\nu)$ in direction $\phi\nu$. So let $\Phi_t$ be the the family of diffeomorphisms generated by $\phi \nu$ and $\nu_t$ be the unit normal of $\Sigma_t = \Phi_t(\Sigma)$. The abbreviated notation $\partial_t \nu_t = \partial_t\Phi_t^*\nu_t$ is used here.
The first step in the calculation is then
$\partial_t k(\nu, \nu) = (\partial_t k)(\nu, \nu) + 2k(\partial_t \nu, \nu)$,
which I have no issue with. But then they go on in the next line and say that
$(\partial_t k)(\nu, \nu) = \phi(\nabla_\nu k)(\nu, \nu)$.
And this is the part I don't understand. I was thinking that $\partial_t k = L_{\phi\nu}k$. But clearly the Lie derivative of a (0,2)-tensor is not equal to $\phi(\nabla_\nu k)(\nu, \nu)$ or is it?
What is the definition of $\partial_t$ here and why is or isn't it the Lie derivative?
